# Device has screen shots that I didn't take - Security Risk?

Tags: security, screenshots

Quite unintentionally, I clicked open this system folder

```
/data/system/recent_images
```

to find screenshots of apps used, images from sites visited and you tube videos

Googling this, led me to this [GitHub post](https://github.com/4n0m41y/raats) which claims that it could be a possible *NSA backdoor* and that screenshots correspond to entries in

```
 /data/system/recent_tasks
```

**Can somebody explain the purpose behind it and should it be a security concern?**

Comment: Sounds rather like a conspiracy to me. Aren't those the thumbnails used if you scroll through your "recently used apps" list? Of course everything may serve a double purpose.

Comment: @izzy: not all pertain to recent apps, pictures from Chrome browser, for instance- all I did was view them using *image* tab. I am not saying *it is* a designed conspiracy , there could be a sound reason too- curious. Reading that GitHub does give more pointers ( camera) for instance, to support the conspiracy angle and lack of documentation as claimed may or not be a good enough reason to suspect

Comment: And you didn't use Chrome? Or there are multiple thumbnails of it (which would also make sense as, by default, each tab stupidly counts as its own "app"). But as I wrote, I have no sound proof – just pointing out what IMHO those directories are for.

Comment: I did use Chrome but it's got only what is viewed in images tab - that's the only one from Chrome despite multiple tabs used. Let's hope to get some understanding on this